# Error creating a geospatial index on the data after importing data from an excel doc

Tags: excel, mongodb, indexing, geospatial, 2dsphere

I have imported this data from an excel document.

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57440d63a458f726a8f95bfe"),
    "state" : "WEST BENGAL",
    "bank" : "STATE BANK OF INDIA",
    "ifsc" : "SBIN0000001",
    "micr code" : "700002021",
    "branch" : "KOLKATA MAIN",
    "address" : "SAMRIDDHI BHAWAN, 1 STRAND ROAD, KOLKATA 700 001",
    "latlong" : "22.569435,88.342932",
    "latitude" : "22.569435",
    "longitude" : "88.342932",
    "city" : "KOLKATA",
    "district" : "KOLKATA",
    "loc" : [
            "88.34",
            "22.57"
        ]
}
```

This is my sample document. I am unable to create a geospatial index on loc. How to create?

Comment: how are you trying to create index?

Comment: db.sbi.ensureIndex({loc:"2d"})

Comment: looks like the loc field is not in valid format.                                                          The values of the array may be either arrays, as in [ 55.5, 42.3 ], or embedded documents, as in { lng : 55.5 , lat : 42.3 }.

Comment: I tried converting them to float values,but it didn't help db.sbi.find().forEach(function(doc) { doc.loc = [parseFloat(doc.longitude).toFixed(2),parseFloat(doc.latitude).toFixed(2)]; db.sbi.save(doc); });

Comment: can you show us the error you get while creating the index?

Comment: ```db.sbi.ensureIndex({"loc":"2d"})
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "location object expected, location array not in correct format",
        "code" : 16804
}```

Comment: try this:    { "_id" : ObjectId("57440d63a458f726a8f95bfe"), "state" : "WEST BENGAL", "bank" : "STATE BANK OF INDIA", "ifsc" : "SBIN0000001", "micr code" : "700002021", "branch" : "KOLKATA MAIN", "address" : "SAMRIDDHI BHAWAN, 1 STRAND ROAD, KOLKATA 700 001", "latlong" : "22.569435,88.342932", "latitude" : "22.569435", "longitude" : "88.342932", "city" : "KOLKATA", "district" : "KOLKATA", "loc" : [ ["88.34", "22.57" ]] }

Comment: "errmsg" : "geo values must be 'legacy coordinate pairs' for 2d indexes got the error message

Comment: the challenge here is to convert coordinates to float values in loc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values of arrays need to be in special format to create 2D Index.

[Geospatial Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/)

> The values of the array may be either arrays, as in [ 55.5, 42.3 ], or
>   embedded documents, as in { lng : 55.5 , lat : 42.3 }.

I could create 2d index on following document. I think you would need to revisit excel import process.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57440d63a458f726a8f95bfe"),
    "state" : "WEST BENGAL",
    "bank" : "STATE BANK OF INDIA",
    "ifsc" : "SBIN0000001",
    "micr code" : "700002021",
    "branch" : "KOLKATA MAIN",
    "address" : "SAMRIDDHI BHAWAN, 1 STRAND ROAD, KOLKATA 700 001",
    "latlong" : "22.569435,88.342932",
    "latitude" : "22.569435",
    "longitude" : "88.342932",
    "city" : "KOLKATA",
    "district" : "KOLKATA",
    "loc" : [
            88.34,
            22.57
        ]
}
```

Comment: How to convert this part to float values ? "loc" : [
            "88.34",
            "22.57"
        ] ```db.sbi.find().forEach(function(doc) { doc.loc = [parseFloat(doc.longitude).toFixed(2),parseFloat(doc.latitude).toFixed(2)]; db.sbi.save(doc); });``` I tried this

Comment: ```db.sbi.find().forEach(function(doc) {
db.sbi.update( 
           { _id: doc._id}, 
           { $set : { "loc" : [parseFloat(doc.longitude),parseFloat(doc.latitude)] } }
        )
  })``` Done! Thanks

Comment: Great. Thanks for sharing it.